# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at registerNgModuleType Issue

Tags: angular, typeerror, ng-modules

MEAN Stack Project where the front (built with Angular) runs on localhost:4000
The Problem is sometimes the App Crashes displaying a white blank page with the following error in console:

[image]

The issue resolves when I remove node modules folder and reinstall the dependencies
But Doing that frequently is not practical Plus it seems the issue is not resolved

Comment: You are trying to access a property on an object which does not exist yet. This could happen if your data is fetched asynchronously with no guard in your template. Are you perhaps using the `ngFor` directive in your template and accessing `id` there?

Comment: It would help if you also included the associated snippets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohanSwanepoel how can i guard my template if there is an async request ?

Comment: You'll have to share part of your template to be sure, but you typically can assign the result of your async call to an observable and then use the async pipe inside an `ngIf` expression. Something like:

`<ul *ngIf="(myData$ | async) as data"><li *ngFor="let item of data">{{ item.id }}</li></ul>`